# The sound of a damaged car door

Tags: single-word-requests

I am having difficulty describing the sound of grinding metal as it pertains to opening a car door that has been severely damaged in an accident.

Comment: Screeeech!!!!!!

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What words have you already considered and rejected?

Comment: Grinding, scraping. Have you ever come across a heavily damaged car door and tried to open it, only to meet incredibly resistance, to a point when it makes a loud, metal crunching sound because the integrity of the door and quarter panel have been compromised?

Comment: incredible, not incredibly

Comment: "Groan!" is another term often attributed to large metallic parts.

Answer (score 1):

## Scrape/Scraping:

> to grate harshly over or against/a harsh noise made by scraping

Scraping noise demonstrated in this youtube video: [Scraping Noise From Wheel While Driving](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR8UbHpBfmU)

Answer (score 0):

[creaking](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/creak?q=creaking) or [groaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groan)?

Listen to the sound on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1LBTjqlPwE&list=PLCVRODEZMa1iCd5mRCnWS8YndJyQZibK2). Perhaps it's what you're looking for?